# Are `self?` and `guard let self` the same, in a closure?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, closures, self

I was asked in a code review to do this update.

from:

```
func bind(errorText: Driver<String>) {
         errorText.drive(onNext: { [weak self] text in
             self?.set(text: text)
             self?.accessibilityValue = text
         }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
     }
```

to:

```
func bind(errorText: Driver<String>) {
         errorText.drive(onNext: { [weak self] text in
             guard let self = self else { return }
             self.set(text: text)
             self.accessibilityValue = text
         }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
     }
```

The difference is between `self?` and `guard`.

On the 1st code I have the impression that `self?` is released when the variable that it calls is nil. Or is the 2nd way, using the `guard let self`, the 100% way to be sure `self` is released? Thanks

Comment: I personally like to spice it up a bit and name the guard `strongSelf` to make it easier visually to see that the block is strongly referenced. Just my 2c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are practically identical. The main difference is that the first will check whether `self` is nil twice rather than once. Since the first example doesn't hold a strong reference across statements, it is technically possible for the first line to execute, then `self` to be released, and the second line not execute. In the second case, the `guard let` takes a strong reference until the end of the block, at which point `self` will be released.

The latter is generally preferable, though it's not a huge issue either way. It is easier to reason about the `guard let` code when `self` is nil. When you skip over a bunch of statements using `self?.`, any lines that *don't* rely on `self` still execute, which might be surprising. It is also nice in cases where optional chaining isn't appropriate (for example when accessing properties of `self`). So it works the same way in more cases.

Comment: Rob, the bit in your second paragraph about the `guard let` code is confusing, and as written gives me the wrong impression. When you use `guard let...` at the beginning of a closure, the closure will exit if self is nil, and the additional lines that do not rely on self will **not** execute. (Nothing after the `guard let` will execute if self is nil.)

Comment: Thanks @DuncanC. Hopefully reworded in a way that's a bit more clear.